# How do I avoid or workaround: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I keep getting:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

in:

```
line 525, in <module>
        df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'], fill_value=0)
      File "C:\Users\AC\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1070, in flex_wrapper
        return self._binop(other, op, level=level, fill_value=fill_value)
      File "C:\Users\AC\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1715, in _binop
        result = func(this_vals, other_vals)
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

In:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\13.csv',
                  index_col=False,
                  usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3],
                  names=["EW", "WE", "DA", "DD"],
                  header=None)
# print(df1.head())


df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\14.csv',
                  index_col=False,
                  usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                  names=["AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE"],
                  header=None)

df1['EW'] = df1['EW'] + ' v ' + df1['WE']

df1['WE'] = df1['DA']
df1['DA'] = df1['DD']

df2['EW'] = df2['AB'] + ' v ' + df2['AC']

df2['EW'] = df2['AB'] + ' v ' + df2['AC']

df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='EW')
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'WE': 'O1', 'AD': 'O2'})
df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'], fill_value=0)
```

My dataframes look like:

[df1](https://cdn-05.anonfile.com/FaD2o0ddb0/098541d8-1513763067/df1.csv)

```
                 EW           WE    DA  \
0       KV Mechelen  Club Brugge  4.30   
1              Gent    Charleroi  1.75   
2     Royal Antwerp      Lokeren  1.68   
3        Anderlecht        Eupen  1.31   
4  Waasland-Beveren     Oostende  2.20   



                                                  DD  
0  https://www.topsport.com.au/Soccer/Belgian_Jup...  
1  https://www.topsport.com.au/Soccer/Belgian_Jup...  
2  https://www.topsport.com.au/Soccer/Belgian_Jup...  
3  https://www.topsport.com.au/Soccer/Belgian_Jup...  
4  https://www.topsport.com.au/Soccer/Belgian_Jup...
```

[df2](https://cdn-04.anonfile.com/GaD1o5d6ba/08bd92d2-1513763134/df2.csv)

```
             AA                  AB                        AC    AD  \
0     Thu 18:50       Brisbane Roar               Perth Glory  2.24   
1  Dec 22 18:50      Newcastle Jets  Western Sydney Wanderers  2.42   
2  Dec 23 16:35  Wellington Phoenix                    Sydney  7.20   
3  Dec 23 18:50      Melbourne City         Melbourne Victory  3.00   
4  Dec 26 18:50     Adelaide United    Central Coast Mariners  2.14   

                                                  AE  
0  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  
1  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  
2  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  
3  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  
4  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...
```

How do I avoid this error that keeps popping up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is string column `O1`.

So need convert column to `float`:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='EW')
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'WE': 'O1', 'AD': 'O2'})

df3['O1'] = df3['O1'].astype(float)

df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'], fill_value=0)
```

But if there are some non numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for `NaN`s for non parseable values:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='EW')
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'WE': 'O1', 'AD': 'O2'})

df3['O1'] = pd.to_numeric(df3['O1'], errors='coerce')

df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'], fill_value=0)
```

Comment: There is wrong pasted code, need after rename to `O1`, check edit.